# Extending or adding action to a function

Tags: php, function, extend

Is it possible to extend a php function ?

if no how does WordPress `add_action()` works ?

can you guys suggest me `add_action` like function for non wordpress system ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I got what I was looking for,

https://github.com/bainternet/PHP-Hooks

This class works great, thanks to Bainternet